# Where do I put jar files in Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, jsp, jar, tomcat6

I am having trouble getting my JSP page to load a Java class which is in a jar file.  The message I get appears to indicate a class not found exception:

```
Jan 6, 2011 12:21:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 72 in the jsp file: /xmlloader.jsp
FactArray cannot be resolved to a type
69:         sourceType = "1";
70: }
71: 
72: FactArray fa = new FactArray();
73: Fact f;
74: 
75: /***********************/
```

The Type `FactArray` is one of my classes in a package com.mypackage.fact.FactArray which exists in myjar.jar.  myjar.jar is a separate Java project (using NetBeans, but I don't think that's relevant).

I include the package in my JSP as follows:

```
<%@ page import="com.mypackage.fact.*" %>
```

I deploy my web site and JSPs into Tomcat 6 as a WAR file.  I include myjar.jar in that WAR in WEB-INF/lib but that doesn't work.  I tried putting myjar.jar in my tomcat/lib folder, but that doesn't work either.

I have bounced the server several times between changes.  I have read a whole bunch of questions on here which say "put it in WEB-INF/lib" but that isn't working, so I'm asking my own question.

Where do I need to put common JAR files so they get picked up by Tomcat?

Comment: I hope this code is placed before its declaration `<%@ page import="com.mypackage.fact.*" %>`

Comment: yup, declaration before code...

Answer (score 10):

Putting in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the deployed webapp should work.

If that doesn't work, then the possible causes are:

- The JAR doesn't contain the desired class at all (extract with ZIP tool and verify)
- There's a typo in your import and/or class declaration (mind case sensitivity!)

---

Unrelated to the problem, using *scriptlets* is not the best practice. Consider a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: hmm, that's an interesting comment.  Can you say why you think I have a scriptlet (I thought I had a servlet).

Comment: ...wait, I get it...  but it is still interesting.  But now I think I have a knowledge gap.  Instead of that scriptlet what would I do?

Comment: Start here: [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: I also had the same problem with my tomcat. Your solution works for me, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct import statements in the code; depending on how you set up your env, place the jars in the webapps/ROOT/lib